# Can't evaluate Javascript based policy with Keycloak

Tags: javascript, java, keycloak

I'm trying to test the Javascript Based policies defined in this project https://github.com/mposolda/devconf2019-authz/blob/master/cars-realm.json#L191, but everytime I try to access a protected ressource I got the following error in keycloak logs :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find ScriptEngine for script: Script{id='null', realmId='cars', name='Only From a Specific Client Address', type='text/javascript', code='var contextAttributes = $evaluation.getContext().getAttributes();

if (contextAttributes.containsValue('kc.client.network.ip_address', '127.0.0.1')) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}', description='Defines that only clients from a specific address can do something'}
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@15.0.2//org.keycloak.scripting.DefaultScriptingProvider.createPreparedScriptEngine(DefaultScriptingProvider.java:106)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@15.0.2//org.keycloak.scripting.DefaultScriptingProvider.prepareEvaluatableScript(DefaultScriptingProvider.java:72)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@15.0.2//org.keycloak.scripting.DefaultScriptingProvider.prepareEvaluatableScript(DefaultScriptingProvider.java:33)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.JSPolicyProviderFactory.lambda$getEvaluatableScript$0(JSPolicyProviderFactory.java:109)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.ScriptCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ScriptCache.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1224)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.ScriptCache.computeIfAbsent(ScriptCache.java:80)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.JSPolicyProviderFactory.getEvaluatableScript(JSPolicyProviderFactory.java:106)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.js.JSPolicyProvider.evaluate(JSPolicyProvider.java:46)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.aggregated.AggregatePolicyProvider.evaluate(AggregatePolicyProvider.java:66)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.aggregated.AggregatePolicyProvider.evaluate(AggregatePolicyProvider.java:66)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.permission.AbstractPermissionProvider.evaluate(AbstractPermissionProvider.java:56)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-authz-policy-common@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.provider.permission.ScopePolicyProvider.evaluate(ScopePolicyProvider.java:52)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.evaluation.DefaultPolicyEvaluator.lambda$createPolicyEvaluator$0(DefaultPolicyEvaluator.java:116)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$PolicyCache.cacheQuery(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:1098)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$PolicyCache.cacheQuery(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:1073)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$PolicyCache.findByScopeIds(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:1045)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.AuthorizationProvider$3.findByScopeIds(AuthorizationProvider.java:430)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.policy.evaluation.DefaultPolicyEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultPolicyEvaluator.java:86)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.permission.evaluator.UnboundedPermissionEvaluator.lambda$evaluate$0(UnboundedPermissionEvaluator.java:49)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.permission.Permissions.lambda$all$1(Permissions.java:87)
        at java.base/java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$ResourceCache$1.accept(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:678)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$ResourceCache$1.accept(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:673)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.utils.ClosingStream.forEach(ClosingStream.java:128)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.jpa.store.JPAResourceStore.findByOwnerFilter(JPAResourceStore.java:136)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.jpa.store.JPAResourceStore.findByOwner(JPAResourceStore.java:101)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$ResourceCache.lambda$findByOwner$7(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:673)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$ResourceCache.cacheQuery(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:845)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$ResourceCache.cacheQuery(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:830)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.authorization.StoreFactoryCacheSession$ResourceCache.findByOwner(StoreFactoryCacheSession.java:671)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.AuthorizationProvider$4.findByOwner(AuthorizationProvider.java:501)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.permission.Permissions.all(Permissions.java:85)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.authorization.permission.evaluator.UnboundedPermissionEvaluator.evaluate(UnboundedPermissionEvaluator.java:48)
```

Is there any further step I need to do in order to make this example work ?

Keycloak version : 15.0.2
Java version : 15

Thanks !

Comment: What version of java is used by the keycloak server? Rhino was removed in Java 15. If the server uses Java 15+, this is expected behaviour. If this is the case, then we can either downgrade to Java <=14, or load another JS engine as dependency. For information on the latter option, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259515/how-can-i-continue-to-use-javascript-in-java-15-onwards).

Comment: I'm using Java 15, and switching back to 11 did resolved the problem ! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we look at the first line of the log message:

```
Could not find ScriptEngine for script: Script{ ... type='text/javascript'... }
```

we see that keycloak is not able to load a javascript scripting engine.

Since Java >= 15, no javascript engine is provided with the JVM (see [JEP 372](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372)). This is the reason why keycloak cannot find a javascript engine.

I see two possible solutions to the problem:

- Provide a javascript engine through some 3rd party libraries (for detail see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259515/how-can-i-continue-to-use-javascript-in-java-15-onwards) by [Paul Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480018/paul-taylor)), or
- Downgrade Java to <= 14 (not recommended).