# cannot locate jjs in mac os 10.15.7

Tags: java, macos, macos-catalina

when I run jjs in bash on Mac. I got:

> Unable to locate an executable at
> "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jjs"
> (-1)

Java version:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode,
> sharing)

I tried to find jjs by finder but nothing was available. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find `jjs` because it is not part of Java 17.

The Nashorn Javascript implementation and `jjs` were deprecated in Java 11 and removed in Java 15.  There is no replacement in Oracle or OpenJDK Java 17.

If you need to continue using a Javascript interpreter in Java 15 or later, see the following for possible alternatives.

- [How can I continue to use Javascript in Java 15 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259515)

If you need a stand-alone Javascript implementation on a Mac, one possible alternative is Node.js.  There could be others.